# What is a marker trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I am learning Rust and want to dive into marker traits. Definition from official documentation is not clear for me: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/index.html

Definition:

> Primitive traits and types representing basic properties of types. Rust types can be classified in various useful ways according to their intrinsic properties. These classifications are represented as traits.

1. Why do we  define a special group of traits and calling this group "marker traits"? What is special about these traits?
2. Did I understand correctly that all these traits have default implementation and we can derive these traits for our custom structs without implementation?

Could you please answer with help of examples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Marker traits are used to *mark* types as having some *property*. They usually don't have any associated types and methods and are used to tell the compiler about some property of a type. Note that some of those traits are [auto traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits), which means that the compiler will automatically implement them for types, if it reasons it is safe to do so (you can still implement them manually, but it may require `unsafe` keyword).

Currently (`rustc 1.70.0`) there are 5 stable traits in `std::marker` module. They have the following meaning. If type `T` implements:

- `Copy` it means that it can be `Clone`d by using bitwise copy
- `Send` it means that value of type `T` can be send across thread boundary
- `Sync` it means that value of type `T` can be shared between threads (that is `&T` is `Send`)
- `Sized` means that size of type `T` is known at compile time
- `Unpin` means that value of type `T` can be moved after it was [pinned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html)

Of those above `Send`, `Sync` and `Unpin` are auto traits. There are also two more stable auto traits in [std::panic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/index.html) module.

To answer your questions.

> Why do we define a special group of traits and calling this group "marker traits"? What is special about these traits?

We call these traits "markers", to distinguish between implementation of interfaces and providing information about type properties to the compiler, both of which are accomplished in rust with traits. However there is nothing *special* about them. These are normal traits as all others. This is just a semantic name for us, humans.

> Did I understand correctly that all these traits have default implementation and we can derive these traits for our custom structs without implementation?

They don't have [default implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations) strictly speaking, because by this term we understand default implementation of trait's method that is shared with all types that implement given trait and can be by them overwritten. Like for example [std::io::Write::write_all](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all).

However since they don't have any methods we can simply implement them for our types by just saying that this type implements this trait. For example we can implement `Copy` for our type like this (we will used `#[derive(Clone)]` so that we don't have to implement it manually, since `Clone` is a [supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) of `Copy`):

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
    b: f32,
    c: bool,
}

impl Copy for Foo {}
```

You can also implement auto traits, that compiler didn't implement automatically. For example any type that contains a *raw pointer* is automatically marked as [!Send](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html#impl-Send-for-*const+T) ([negative implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html) are unstable feature that compiler uses). However if it is **safe** to send such type between threads you can explicitly implement `Send` for it (note that you must use `unsafe` keyword, since wrong implementations of `Send` can result in undefined behavior:

```rust
struct Bar {
    ptr: *const (),
}

unsafe impl Send for Bar {}
```

Once exception however is trait `Sized`, which can solely be implemented by the compiler. Trying to implement it manually will result in an [E0322](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0322.html) error.

Comment: _"`Copy` is a supertrait of `Clone`"_ -- If I am not mistaken, it is the other way around.

Comment: @cdhowie "The trait your trait definition is relying on is called a *supertrait* of your trait." ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait)). You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The term *marker* is used in computer languages for traits without much code. Only the presence of some trait (=the object is *marked*) is exploited in processing. For example using a list of that marker trait. Java's `Number` or `Serializable` might be such a marker.